# Can I host a hidden service on Amazon EC2

Tags: onion-services, ec2

I only have 1mbps upspeed and can't host a hidden service from home, is it a good idea to use Amazon EC2? I already use it for other sites, but what about for a tor site.

Comment: amazon is NSA company, the same as paypal, visa, mastercard, etc. even for moral reasons, nobody should use companies that blocked wikileaks. but more important, if you host something at amazon, connected with tor, it should not involve other people because they can be arrested if you didn't tell them about risk.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably no reason why that wouldn't work.  There already are tor bridge relays in EC2, using Tor to provide a hidden service probably would also Just Work.